# Exponential thinning of Poisson Process

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process

Let $(N_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Poisson Process of parameter $\lambda>0$ whose arrival times are $(T_k)_{k\ge1}$. Consider a thinning of $(N_t)_{t\ge0}$ such that we remove an arrival time $T_k=t$ with probability $\pi(t)=1-e^{-at}$ where $a>0$ independantly of other arrival times. Determine the probability that at least one arrival time is observed in $[1,\infty)$.

If we let $A$ be the event "at least one arrival time is observed in $[1,\infty)$", $A_k$ be the event "the arrival time $T_k$ is removed" and $k_0=\min\{k\ge 1, T_k\ge 1\}$, then we have :
$$\mathbb P(A)=1-\mathbb P(A^c)=1-\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{k=k_0}^\infty A_k\right)=1-\prod_{k=k_0}^\infty\mathbb P(A_k)=1-\prod_{k=k_0}^\infty\pi(T_k)$$
where the $3$rd equality is obtained thanks to the independance of the $(A_k)$. The issue now is that the right-hand side is fairly difficult to compute and I'm not quite sure where to go from there. I also tried calculating $\mathbb P(A)$ directly by using subsets of $[\![k_0,\infty[\![$ but again to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the probability that an arrival is observed between $t$ and $t + dt$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I approached this problem.

Let $[x,y)$ be an interval and $\{[t_{i-1},t_i),s_i\}_{i=1}^n$ a tagged partition of $[x,y)$.

If $n$ is very large, the arrival process in $[t_{i-1},t_i)$ splits $-$ those arrivals which survive and those that don't. The counting process for surviving arrivals is approximately $\text{Poisson}\left(\lambda \Delta t_i e^{-as_i}\right)$ where $\Delta t_{i}=t_i-t_{i-1}$.

This means the surviving arrivals on $[x,y)$ is approximately $\text{Poisson}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda \Delta t_i e^{-as_i}\right)$ which approaches $\text{Poisson}\left(\int_x^y\lambda e^{-at}\mathrm{d}t\right)$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

Now take $x=1$ and $y=\infty$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a special case of a sampled Poisson process or **non-homogeneous Poisson process**:

Suppose we have a Poisson process in which there are $k$ possible types of events, and suppose that the probability that an event is of type $i$ is time-dependent, say $P_i(t)$. We then have the following result:

**Proposition.** If $N_i(t)$ represents the number of type-$i$ events occurring by time $t$, then $N_i(t)$, $i = 1,\ldots,k$, are independent Poisson random variables having means
$$ E\big(N_i(t)\big) = \lambda \int_0^t P_i(s) \,ds \text{.} $$

I found this claim as Proposition 5.3 of *Introduction to Probability Models* by Sheldon M. Ross, though I'm sure that there are freely accessible proofs on the Web as well.

Applied to your question, the number of observed events after time $t = 1$ is a Poisson random variable with expected value $\lambda e^{-a} / a$. That should help you get the probability you're looking for.